# Can I annotate a custom variant of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with @Component

Tags: java, spring

I annotated `MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`(extends `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`) with `@Component` but I am not able to access values read from the file. The same works when I create the bean using `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class. What I am doing is picking up the key-value pairs from a. properties file and decrypting the values and saving it into a `Map` data member inside a singleton bean class.

Why is it that when I register a bean for this class using `@Bean` inside a `@Configuration` class, it works. But when I register it using `@Component` with component scan including the package of this file, it gives me a `null` value for the requested key?

Comment: Because a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a special bean and it needs to be a `public static` `@Bean` method to work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for confirming this. I am new to spring and went over the docs but wasn't able to develop a full understanding. If you don't mind could you please help me understand the below. 
1. How does the life cycle of the PPC work? I know it is instantiated before any other beans and is alive only to fulfill the dependencies of other beans. Does this happen so early, that it's before component scanning and Component doesn't work.
2. I understand making the Bean method static will lead to early creation of the PPC. Is there a way to replicate this with XML or Component based annotation too?

Comment: With XML you only need to define your bean nothing more. Java and XML configs are processed entirely different and due to the different languages used (and thus parsing) you need to have a `public static` method. Configuration classes are parsed very early in the process when reading configuration. When component scanning and detecting `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instances it would simply be too late to process/modify the configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and sharing your knowledge. Appreciate it a lot.